# Unexpected Failure of Individual Assertions when Spying a Function with Different Arguments using vitest

Tags: testing, vitest

I am currently encountering an issue while spying on a function using vitest and attempting to assert that it is called with specific arguments. The function I am testing internally calls another function four times, each time with a different argument. I have defined an array `expectedArgs` containing the expected arguments for these function calls.

Here is a simplified representation of the code structure:

```js
const expectedArgs = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// Function under test
function myFunction() {
  // ...
  mySpiedFunc(1);
  mySpiedFunc(2);
  mySpiedFunc(3);
  mySpiedFunc(4);
  // ...
}

// Spy on mySpiedFunc
const mySpiedFunc = vi.spyOn(objectContainingMyFunction, 'mySpiedFunc');

// Test case
it('should call mySpiedFunc with expected arguments', () => {
  myFunction();

  expect(mySpiedFunc).toBeCalledWith(1);
  expect(mySpiedFunc).toBeCalledWith(2);
  expect(mySpiedFunc).toBeCalledWith(3);
  expect(mySpiedFunc).toBeCalledWith(4);
});
```

In an ideal scenario where all instances of `mySpiedFunc` are called with the expected arguments (1, 2, 3, and 4), the test passes without any issues.

However, I have observed that if, for instance, the third call to `mySpiedFunc` mistakenly uses `5` instead of `3`, then, instead of only the third assertion failing, all subsequent assertions also fail, displaying a diff-like output:

```
1st spy call return:
- 1
+ 5
2nd spy call return:
- 2
+ 5
...
```

I would anticipate that only the assertion for the incorrect argument (3) would fail, while the other assertions for 1, 2, and 4 would pass.

I am using vitest for mocking and spying in my testing framework. I would greatly appreciate any insights, explanations, or potential workarounds for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for this. The problem was that I was expecting `toBeCalledWith` to check each call in order (first `toBeCalledWith` for 1, second for 2, etc.).

`toBeCalledWith` will check *every* mock call. If there was no match, it will show an error message for each check made.

If you want to check each mock call *in order* then you can use [toHaveBeenNthCalledWith](https://vitest.dev/api/expect.html#tohavebeennthcalledwith) or [toHaveNthReturnedWith](https://vitest.dev/api/expect.html#tohaventhreturnedwith), depending on your use case.

Changing the initial code like this:

```js
it('should call mySpiedFunc with expected arguments', () => {
  myFunction();

  // toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(<index-starting-from-1>, <value-to-be-called-with>)
  expect(mySpiedFunc).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 1);
  expect(mySpiedFunc).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, 2);
  expect(mySpiedFunc).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(3, 3);
  expect(mySpiedFunc).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(4, 4);
});
```

will provide the expected behavior (fail on first unexpected value).